# Question about a real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence and for any $n>1$ let $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{2k}$. Then which of the following options are correct?

1. If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ exists, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ exists.
2. If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ exists, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$  need not exist.
3. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ exists.
4. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ need not exist.

In my opinion 2 and 3 are correct. But I have found that 2 and 4 are correct. How 4 is correct? I have not found any clue. Please help!

Comment: Why do you think 3. is correct, say? Unless you say that, there is no question here, I am afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a_n = (-1)^n \tfrac 1n$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \tfrac 1n$ exists but not $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n} \tfrac 1{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tfrac 1{2n}$.

Comment: Write \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n} \tfrac 1{2n} instead of \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^2n \tfrac 1{2n}

Comment: @Scientifica: Thanks, I have corrected my mistake... ;-)

Comment: It's a pleasure! +1 for the answer ;)